# Convert ISO datetime string to standard date format in Freemarker

Tags: date, format, freemarker

How can I convert a string in an iso date format like

```
"2015-06-28T03:39:43.176Z"
```

to look like

```
"2015-06-28 03:39:43 PDT" using Freemarker?
```

I tried some things like:

```
${x.Start?datetime(iso)?datetime}
${x.Start?datetime.iso?datetime}
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the `string` builting to convert the datetime variable, created from your string with the `datetime.iso` built-in. `${"2015-06-28T03:39:43.176Z"?datetime.iso?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz")}` works for me.

Comment: Either that, or OP should set the `datatime_format` setting to his preferred format, and then simply writing `${x.Start?datetime.iso}` should do that.